# How to group by a column a data frame in pandas and get all other columns data in Json array?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        "Column1": ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
        "Column2": ['x1', 'x2', 'z1', 'z2', 'm1', 'm2', 'm3'],
        "Column3": ['y1', 'y2', 'd1', 'd2', 'n1', 'n2', 'n3']
})
```

How do I group by column one to get the following output

`Column1 | new_column
-------  | --------|--------
A        | [{"Column2": "x1", "Column3": "y1"}, {"Column2": "x2","Column3": "y2"}]
B        | [{"Column2": "z1", "Column3": "d1"}, {"Column2": "z2","Column3": "d2"}]
C        | [{"Column2": "m1", "Column3": "n1"}, {"Column2": "m2","Column3": 
          "m2"},{"Column2": "m3", "Column3": "n3"}]`

I need to do this to join another dataframe with Column1.

Thank you

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? Most Pandas operations are more easily accomplished starting from the original DataFrame, and can only be done more clumsily starting from the second...

Comment: It's possible, and probably advisable, to merge `df` with the other DataFrame on `Column1` without forming `new_column` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
df_out =  df.groupby('Column1')\
            .apply(lambda x: x.drop('Column1',axis=1).to_dict(orient='record'))\
            .reset_index(name='new_column')
```

Output:

```
  Column1                                         new_column
0       A  [{'Column3': 'y1', 'Column2': 'x1'}, {'Column3...
1       B  [{'Column3': 'd1', 'Column2': 'z1'}, {'Column3...
2       C  [{'Column3': 'n1', 'Column2': 'm1'}, {'Column3...
```

Use to_dict to display full dataframe

```
df_out.to_dict()
```

Output:

```
 'A': [{'Column2': 'x1', 'Column3': 'y1'}, {'Column2': 'x2', 'Column3': 'y2'}],
 'B': [{'Column2': 'z1', 'Column3': 'd1'}, {'Column2': 'z2', 'Column3': 'd2'}],
 'C': [{'Column2': 'm1', 'Column3': 'n1'},
  {'Column2': 'm2', 'Column3': 'n2'},
  {'Column2': 'm3', 'Column3': 'n3'}]}
```